# Config parser with ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr4

i have some problems creating a config parser with ANTLR 4. The config files have the following syntax:

```
section1{
key=value;
key=value;
}

section2{
key=value;
}
```

I have also written a lexer/parser:

```
grammar Config;

fragment IdentifierText: [A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*;
fragment IdentifierNumber:[0-9]+'.'?[0-9]*;
fragment IdentifierBool: 'false'|'true';
Section: IdentifierText;
Key: [A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*;
Value: IdentifierText|IdentifierNumber|IdentifierBool;
Whitespace: [\t\b \f\r\n]+ -> skip;

start: configs;

configs: config+;

config:  section  statement ;

statement: '{' assignment+ '}';

section: Section;

assignment:  Key '=' Value ';';
```

But if I use this as a sample:

```
Test{
debug=false;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
line 2:0 mismatched input 'debug' expecting Key
line 2:5 mismatched input '=' expecting '{'
line 2:11 mismatched input ';' expecting '{'
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Section` lexer rule is indistinguishable from `Key`. When an input matching one of these rules is found, the ambiguity is resolved by choosing the first one that appears in your grammar; in this case `Section`. In other words, it is impossible for the lexer as you have defined it to return a `Key` token.

You should resolve this by using a single `Identifier` rule for both sections and keys, and using parser rules to distinguish between them.

```
section : Identifier;
key : Identifier;
Identifier : IdentifierText;
```